# Define static atomic variable in source file is bad?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, static, atomic

If we define static global variable in a source file(.cpp),

```
 // variable defined in cpp
 static std::atomic<double> fps = -1.0;
 static std::atomic<BOOL>isSysUp = FALSE;//WinAPI boolean
 static std::atomic<bool> isMessaginDone = false;

void foo()
{
   while(isSysUp && isMessaginDone ) // with seq.consistent memory order
   {
      //.... some code //
     sleep(1ms);
   }
}
void bar()
{
  if(isSysUp )
  {
    if(/.. condition ../ ) 
      {
         isMessaginDone = false;  

      }    
 }
}

void termi()
{
   isSysUp = false;
}
```

Here **foo** invokes with main thread and **other functions** invoke with child threads.

Say function **foo** calls every **10ms** of cycle like a ***game loop***.
Using ***std::atomic*** with **static** internal linkage and do their **load** and **store** operation in  **memory_order_seq_cst** is reduce performance ? and unsafe?

Is it wise to use ***std::store(std::memory_order_release)***, ***std::load(std::memory_order_acquire)*** with above cases to gain performance with thread-safety?

(Because in function ***foo*** only reading atomic bools rather than writing it once as in functions ***bar*** and ***termi***)

Comment: yes it reduce performance.I  guess u should go for Locking mutex and In your code I can see spin lock try get rid of this too.

Comment: @RohiniSingh where it reduce performance? Spin lock! but is it bad to use Load and store in  memory_order_seq_cst  ?

Comment: yes performance will be slow since it has to sync with all the thread I suggest if you really need it go else drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a static atomic in a compilation unit is as bad or as necessary as using a static global variable in compilation unit.

Performance issues might arise from a bottleneck. But this is more related to the use of shared variables between the thread and consistency requirements than subtle memory ordering issues.

Although this is implementation dependent, atomics on simple basic types such as bool or int are often implemented with support of atomic CPU instructions so that there may be no performance issue at all.

For example, with your definition:

```
   while (!isMessaginDone)
```

would be translated into

```
   movzx eax, BYTE PTR isMessaginDone[rip]  ; already atomic CPU instruction
   test al, al
```

and a setting like

```
   isMessaginDone=true;
```

would become

```
   mov BYTE PTR isMessaginDone[rip], 1
   mfence           ;  compiler is taking care of the memory ordering
```

On the other hand, implementations are free to use lock based implementation of atomic (e.g. with semaphores and the like) which would require a costy OS call.  But in this case again, tricking with memory ordering would not change the cost of the CPU call and will not bring the performance gains that you'd expect.

So don't get lost in attempts of premature optimization. Use the atomics, look at the asm and if needed, perform benchmarks.

Comment: thank you for the answer really helpful.why using static is bad here for translation unit rather than declaring it as non-static global?

Comment: @Buddhika static global is definitively better than non static global. I think it is sometimes necessary and even justified to have such a global. But I'm not qualified to judge for your specific case. Sometimes globals are used for convenience instead of a better engineering of class interactions. This is why I leave good/bad open and focus on the atomic.

Comment: If you don't mind can you tell ,other than std::atomic which kind of approach is most suitable regarding both performance and safety wise for this kind of scenario ? using interlocks/semaphores? or  using mutexes/critical sections? or other technique? I know using mutex/critical sections come with performance penalty relative to other approaches ..  what is the better trick? :)

Comment: Personally, I love atomics. However designign lock free algorithms can be much more difficult than assumed. So mutexes are often used to protect critical sections. If you want to know more, i'd highly recommend "c++ concurrency in action" from Anthony Williams (who is from time to time on SO). It' a great book on concurrency, threads and atomics and c++ (https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action).

Comment: @Buddhika If you want to go in depth on atomics only, there's a nice conference from Herb Sutter available for free here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2

Comment: @Chistophe thanks for the links ..So using atomics for the above case is fine right?

Comment: @Buddhika it depends on the content of the while loop. You access the flags atomically, so there's no risk of race, and you'll use the latest value known at evaluation. However the && is not atomic. So that when you enter the loop, one of the flags could already be false. Up to you to see if this might have unexpected consequences.

Comment: @Chirstophe yeah && is fine to my logic because if one of a flag is false first the thread should be finished(while loop should be broken first priority has been given to that flag to be flase.) yeah I know mostly instead of && if some one has logic with || (respect to their logic) there would be a problem.